# Understanding a vulnerability

Tags: chrome

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=68439

I am having a little bit of trouble understanding this report.

From what i have read, it appears as though removing certain dom nodes triggers a tab crash within chrome.

```
When removing certain nodes, a jump to null is triggered in each of the two cases.
```

What does jump to null mean? I have tried searching up on information on it, but it isn't really clear to me.

Any assistance is very much appreciated.

Comment: my guess is jmp 0x00000000

Comment: Not far from it, and it earned the reporter $2000. Nice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two vulnerabilities, each triggering a jump to address zero:

The first, inside `markContainingBlocksForLayout`:

```
  Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
  [Switching to Thread 0xb09fdb70 (LWP 2039)]
> 0x00000000 in ?? ()
  (gdb) bt
> #0  0x00000000 in ?? ()
  #1  0x0194b82b in markContainingBlocksForLayout (this=0x2e29944, owner=
      0x2e298e4, oldChild=0x0, fullRemove=true)
      at third_party/WebKit/WebCore/rendering/RenderObject.h:946
```

Here's the assembly dump at the faulting eip:

```
   0x0194b81b <removeChildNode(...)+1083>:  decl   -0x74ffd98c(%ebp)
   0x0194b821 <removeChildNode(...)+1089>:  push   %es
   0x0194b822 <removeChildNode(...)+1090>:  mov    %esi,(%esp)
   0x0194b825 <removeChildNode(...)+1093>:  call   *0xb0(%eax)
=> 0x0194b82b <removeChildNode(...)+1099>:  test   %al,%al
   0x0194b82d <removeChildNode(...)+1101>:  jne    0x194b67d <removeChildNode(...)+669>
   0x0194b833 <removeChildNode(...)+1107>:  mov    -0x24(%ebp),%edi
   0x0194b836 <removeChildNode(...)+1110>:  mov    -0x28(%ebp),%esi
   0x0194b839 <removeChildNode(...)+1113>:  jmp    0x194b728 <removeChildNode(...)+840>
```

The `call` instruction calls to the address at `eax + 0xb0`, which implies that `0x02e294f8` is zero (since eax is `0x02e29448`).

Here's the second one, inside `RenderObject::destroy`:

```
  Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
  [Switching to Thread 0xb1646b70 (LWP 2100)]
> 0x00000000 in ?? ()
  (gdb) bt
> #0  0x00000000 in ?? ()
  #1  0x0194387f in WebCore::RenderObject::destroy (this=0x2e29cc4)
      at third_party/WebKit/WebCore/rendering/RenderObject.cpp:2152
```

And the disassembly at eip again:

```
   0x0194386f <WebCore::RenderObject::destroy()+15>:    xchg   %eax,%ebx
   0x01943870 <WebCore::RenderObject::destroy()+16>:    incb   0x3dd4a3c3(%ecx)
   0x01943876 <WebCore::RenderObject::destroy()+22>:    add    %ecx,0x24348906(%ebx)
   0x0194387c <WebCore::RenderObject::destroy()+28>:    call   *0x24(%eax)
=> 0x0194387f <WebCore::RenderObject::destroy()+31>:    test   %eax,%eax
   0x01943881 <WebCore::RenderObject::destroy()+33>:    je     0x194388b <WebCore::RenderObject::destroy()+43>
   0x01943883 <WebCore::RenderObject::destroy()+35>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x01943886 <WebCore::RenderObject::destroy()+38>:    call   0x194a680 <WebCore::RenderObjectChildList::destroyLeftoverChildren()>
   0x0194388b <WebCore::RenderObject::destroy()+43>:    mov    0x8(%esi),%eax
   0x0194388e <WebCore::RenderObject::destroy()+46>:    mov    0x14(%eax),%eax
```

This time, it's `eax + 0x24`, and eax is `0x02e29d38`, giving us `0x02e29d5c`. This implies that the memory at `0x02e29d5c` is also zero.

The distance from `0x02e294f8` to `0x02e29d38` (just less than 2KB) implies that there are two separate allocations being accessed here, so they're almost definitely both different bugs.

The [patch diff](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/75810) for the fix indicates that this is a use-after-free issue, where objects were being "merged" at the same time as being deleted. This may be vulnerable to a race condition, where the memory is deallocated, then re-allocated elsewhere in a probabilistic fashion, then jumped to by this bug, but I can't tell without really digging into it.

You could test the exploitability by doing a lot of memory allocations in a loop within your JavaScript (string manipulation is a good one) and then causing the fault during the loop. If the memory is overwritten, the use-after-free might attempt a jump to some of your string's value.

Comment: Very clear explanation of the vulnerability! Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. I might have a real play with it tonight to see what I can come up with as far as a PoC exploit goes.